# How to change icon of an webapp created with Chromium?

Tags: icons, chromium

I've created a webapp for a website with Chromium. The problem is that the icon it's a small size one and it doesn't look nice.
How can I change the icon with one created by me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is downloading a picture (preferably .png format with at least 96x96 pixel) and then right-clicking on the application link.
Go to properties and click on the icon shown on the left-hand side of the properties dialog.
You can now choose a picture.
Point to the location you have saved the picture you want to use at (for example Downloads) and then just select the image file you'd like to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't know why I haven't think of that. I guess I'm used to have a button "change icon".

Answer (score 0):

When you save the webapp, save it to Desktop only. Open a text editor, such as gedit or Kate, and press Ctrl+O to Open a file. Navigate to your desktop within the file open dialog and you will see a file named "chrome_http___....desktop" or something similar. Open it and then replace the line that says `Icon:chrome-http___...` (or similar) and replace it with `Icon:/home/[username]/path/to/icon/you/want.png`.
   To put the application in your Dash/Kickoff/Activities/Menu/Whatever launcher, press Alt+F2 then run

```
gksu nautilus
```

or, on KDE

```
kdesu dolphin
```

from there, navigate to the file for the webapp and copy it to /usr/share/applications

Note that launching the webapp will still show it in your launcher/dock/Icon-Only-Task-Manager as Chromium, not by it's name and icon. I do not know of a way to fix this, please edit this or comment if you do.

Comment: Well, I've done as Daniel said and the icon is shown on the dock/launcher. Just change the icon and than drag it to the dock and it will be fine, at least in my case.

Comment: take a look at http://superuser.com/questions/1015796/in-kde-plasma-5-how-to-i-create-standalone-launchers-desktop-shortcuts-to-web-a/1068709#1068709 for a solution for fixing how the launcher displays the webapp; This also fixes the ability to pin a launcher.

Answer (score 0):

The default webapp icons are in ~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/

Ubuntu will look for the icons in the order of the size, i.e. from 192x192 all the way down to 16x16.